# Get SOST database ID of sent emails

Tags: email, abap, identification

I have an ABAP program that sends emails. A sent email is stored in SOOD table. After sending an email I would like to get some ID of the email to be able to check its status later (in SOST table). I have seen more functions/methods to send email (e.g. cl_bcs/send, SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1), but none of them returns any ID. Is there a reliable way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other answers gave me together valuable clues to get it done (+1). But both missed some accuracy and code snippets, so I sum it all up in my answer.

### using cl_bcs

```
DATA gr_send_request  TYPE REF TO cl_bcs.
DATA emailid LIKE soodk.
gr_send_request = cl_bcs=>create_persistent( ).

" ...

CALL METHOD gr_send_request->send(EXPORTING i_with_error_screen = 'X'
                                  RECEIVING result = gv_sent_to_all ).

IF gv_sent_to_all = 'X'.
  emailid = gr_send_request->send_request->doc_wrapper_id( ).
ENDIF.
```

`SOODK` (not sood) is structure containing three components (`OBJTP`, `OBJYR`, `OBJNO`) which are together the key in `SOOD` table.

### using SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1

```
DATA LT_OBJECTID TYPE SOFOLENTI1-OBJECT_ID.

CALL FUNCTION 'SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1'
  EXPORTING
    DOCUMENT_DATA              = LT_MAILSUBJECT
    DOCUMENT_TYPE              = 'HTM'
  IMPORTING
    new_object_id              = lt_objectid
" ...
```

`lt_objectid` (`SOFOLENTI1-OBJECT_ID`) is char(17), that contains concatenated `SOODK` structure `OBJTP+OBJYR+OBJNO`. When divided to parts, it can be used to lookup a record in `SOODK` table. (I didn't find it in `BCST_SR-SCOM_KEY`, but it was not necessary.)

Answer (score 4):

Function module `SO_NEW_DOCUMENT_SEND_API1` create and export a new `OBJECT_ID` for every new message sent, As you can see in here -

[image]

This `NEW_OBJECT_ID` stored at **`BCST_SR`**  table in `SCOM_KEY` field. From **`BCST_SR`** table you've to get `DOC_OID`, using `DOC_OID` you can get details from **`SOOD`** table. (Reference field in **`SOOD`** is - `IF_DOC_BCS` ) Then use the Object number `OBJNO` to get the details from **`SOST`** table.

Also you can refer t-code **`SBWP`** to check your mail status.

Comment: is it possible to relate it to the process control case guid?

Answer (score 1):

For class CL_BCS, you can check the send_request object's method doc_wrapper_id. This will return the sood structer.

[image]

[image]